# How -1 indicates end of file while reading external .txt file?

Tags: java

In below code we comparing the value with -1 to check whether its end of file or not, Why we using -1 here to compare?

```
while((i=fin.read())!=-1)
{  
  System.out.println((char)i);  
}
```

Comment: did you read the javadocs for this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote the Javadoc, the `read()` method

> Returns:
>       The number of characters read, or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached

Answer (score 1):

Thats why the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()) of Inputstream says:

> public abstract int read()
>                     throws IOException  Reads the next byte of data from the input stream. The value byte is returned as an int in the range 0
>   to 255. If no byte is available because the end of the stream has been
>   reached, the value -1 is returned. This method blocks until input data
>   is available, the end of the stream is detected, or an exception is
>   thrown.  A subclass must provide an implementation of this method. 
>   Returns:the next byte of data, or -1 if the end of the stream is
>   reached. Throws:

Answer (score 0):

-1 indicates that the end of stream has been reached

so in your case `(i=fin.read())!=-1` you can keep on reading from the stream and as soon as the end of the stream is reached i.e. no more data left the `read` method will return you `-1` and you can come out of the loop